# What's this kanji? 「室」

Tags: kanji, writing-identification

[image: Sign at a stairway in Japan]

**tl;dr: What is the kanji after [管理人]{かんりにん}?**

I did not have any problem finding all the other kanji I didn't know, but the very last one after [管理人]{かんりにん} still puzzles me. I tried googling [管理人]{かんりにん} hoping to find the same kanji after it. I tried finding it via radicals on [Jisho.org](http://jisho.org/) to no avail. It looks a lot like 宀 + 王, 宀 + 主, or 宀 + 里 (esp. given the way 理 is written). The only similar kanji I found would be [宝]{たから}, which does not make sense to me (or Google Translate: [管理人]{かんりにん}[宝]{たから} = treasure trove).

Comment: 「静かに」の「静」って漢字がちょっと違いますよね・・旧字体とかですかね？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is 室{しつ}, usually "room", but also sometimes used in the meaning "office".